# Ajax Request Works via Browser, not via Cordova app in iOS or Android emulators

Tags: android, jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

I've got a jQuery Phonegap app I'm building. The following Ajax request works in my browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

    // Load Meet List
    var requestData = {
        'action' : "getmeetlist"
    };

    $.ajax({
        type    : 'GET',
        url     : 'http://forum.mastersswimmingqld.org.au/swimman/xmltest.php',
        data    : requestData,
        datatype: 'xml',
        encode  : true,
        error: function(xhr, settings, exception){
             alert('The update server could not be contacted.');
        },
    })

    .done (function(data) {

        // Render data
        $(data).find('meet').each(function(){

            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var meetName = $(this).find('meetname').text();

            var startDate = $(this).find('startdate').text();

            $("#meetlist").append("<li><a id=\"" + id + "\" class=\"meetLink\"><h2>" + meetName + "</h2><p>" + startDate + "</p></a></li>");

        }); 

        $("#meetlist").listview('refresh');

    });
```

However, when I run it via either emulators it never works. I have the following in my config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Any suggestions? I've read up on the whitelisting and jQuery pages about Phonegap apps. Still no luck no matter what I do. The only clue I have is that often when I hit this page via the browser(particularly if I arrive via the back button) the list doesn't appear until I hit refresh.

I have put these headers in the php that generates my xml:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

The later one I put there because when the list doesn't appear, the console shows a message "not well formed", but not usually for the line number where the AJAX requests occur.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  The ajax requests are blocked as cross domain requests.  I had to use jsonp in the following manner to get around this.

```
$.ajax({timeout: 5000,
    url: 'http://yoursite.com/yourscript.php',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    callback: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'yourcallback',
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {'scriptinput':'data string you send'}
});
function yourcallback(response) {
   console.log(response);
}
```

Here's an example of how this works for me on the server side in PHP. You'll need to modify your script to return json.  Pass `SendAnswer()` an object with the data you want returned.

```
function SendAnswer($response)  {
// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
}
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
}
header("content-type: application/json");
$callback = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'callback', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
echo  "$callback(" . json_encode($response) . ")";
}
```

Best of luck with your project.